# Compare url segment and category name with conditional

Tags: categories, conditionals, url, segments, css

I'm trying to write a conditional so that the I can output an `active` css class when the url segment is the same as the category name. Because the url segment includes dashes between each word and small case and the category name have uppercase characters without dashes the `==` operator is not evaluating true. Any advise on how to best accomplish this?

**My Current Code:**

`{if segment_4 == category_name}active{/if}`

**Updated Answer**

Found a solution using Low Seg2Cat plugin to get `category_id` from segment url:

`{if segment_4_category_id == category_id}active{/if}`

Comment: Great stuff, but you should have posted your answer as an answer ("Answer Your Own Question"). It helps others that have similar issues identify your post as containing the answer not just an abandoned question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution using Low Seg2Cat plugin to get category_id from segment url:

`{if segment_4_category_id == category_id}active{/if}`

Comment: Upvote for that :) Also, if you can be bothered, come back in a couple of days and accept your answer, you'll get the points and a warm cozy 'helping others' feeling.